# Dropdown Menu CSS or jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I have used jQuery but what I have achieved so far is pictured in the **First Image.**

**My problem**

- The sub-menu does not take the full-width ( white are in the first image ) like the one that I would like to achieve in the **Third Image.**
- Perhaps the structure is already wrong.
- The `contents` in the sub-menu is aligning to the `menu item`

**Here is the structure:**

```
<ul>
   <li class="menu-item">
      <a class="pages-menu" href="<?php echo get_option('home')?>" title="Home">Home</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
         <li><a href="#">Child 1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Child 2</a></li>
     </ul>
   </li> 

   <li>
      <a class="pages-menu" href="<?php echo get_page_link( 22 ); ?>" title="Islands Banca Cruises">Banca</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu" >
          <li><a href="#">Child 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Child 2</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>     

  <li>
      <a class="pages-menu" href="<?php echo get_page_link( 20 ); ?>" title="Islands Stay Hotels">Hotel</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu" >
          <li><a href="#">Child 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Child 2</a></li>
       </ul>
  </li>

  <li>
      <a class="pages-menu" href="<?php echo get_page_link( 67 ); ?>" title="Islands Pasalubong">Pasalubong</a>
       <ul class="sub-menu" >
          <li><a href="#">Child 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Child 2</a></li>
       </ul>
   </li>    

   <li>
       <a class="pages-menu" href="<?php echo get_page_link( 18 ); ?>" title="Islands Souvenirs">Souvenirs</a>
       <ul class="sub-menu" >
           <li><a href="#">Child 1</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Child 2</a></li>
       </ul>
   </li>   
</ul>
```

**First Image:** Sadly, this is what I have achieved so far. I don't like that the `sub-menu` is aligned to the `Menu Item` I want it to be like the **Third Image**.

[image: Current Menu]

**Second Image:** My menu before hover on the `Menu Items.`

[image: My Menu without hover]

**Third Image:** Hover into a `Menu Item` then a sub-menu like the `sky-blue` box will appear. The `Menu Items` are links to a page that's why I just need to hover on them.

[image: My menu after hover to home]

Thank you in advance for you help.

Comment: provide width to the time , this will keep them alike. and to make your sub-menu full width. provide it 100% width in css. you don't need any jquery.

Comment: please provide your current `CSS`

Comment: @wikijames provide the width to the time? what does that mean? Also I tried width:100% to the ul li ul but then it will only take the width to right and not to the left like in the first image it is aligning to the menu item `home`

Comment: as you are defining your submenu inside the parent ul>li. so, you have to provide parent(position:relative) and dropdown(position:absolute). it will work for sure.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `css` with something like:

```
ul {position:relative} //your main menu ul
.sub-menu {position: absolute;left: 0;top:/*Depends on your menu*/;width: 100%;}
```

Comment: not working hope you have a fidde that looks like the third image

Comment: It's cool. I would like to know if there's a cool transition? or even like slidedown like jquery and that triangle (callout)? so tha I can also accept your answer

Comment: @JohnRobertson, for `slidedown` it's only in jQuery, but you can make a somehow `fadeIn` or `fadeOut` with css `transition`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this style, you'll achieve what you need.

```
<style type="text/css">
ul.awesome-menu{
    background-color: #61f9cc;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 5px;
    display: none;
    width:100%;
}
li.menu-item:hover ul.awesome-menu{
    display: block;
}
.awesome-menu li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 10px;
    background-color: #2a8cd8;
}
```

Comment: the skyblue background goes way off the content ( the white area in the first image ). Also the contents are aligning to the `menu item` which i don't want to happen. See the third image the first box it is not aligning to the `home menu item`

Comment: set ul.awesome-menu{ position:absolute; top:0; left:0; } This will bring it to the left